# Unit_test a method that calls another method that the unit test does not know about

Tags: python, unit-testing

How would you test a simple method that calls another method?  Im attempting to test the wssender method currently.

```
in worker.py
---------------- 
class Worker(self):
    def __init__(self, ws)
        self.ws = ws

    def wssender(self,str):
        newstr = '<br>{0}'.format(str)
        self.ws.sendMessage(newstr.encode())
```

and the test code

```
in unit_test.py
-----------------
class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_wssender(self):
        msg = 'test send message'
        wss=worker.Worker
        wss.wssender(wss, msg)
        expected = "<br>test send message"
        self.assertEqual(<something>, expected)
```

There are two issues.   When running this test i get. (ws is a web socket)

```
AttributeError: type object 'Worker' has no attribute 'ws'
```

and 
wssender does not return anything so i'm not sure what to test in this case.

Comment: You're injecting `ws` (I assume websocket) as a dependency to `Worker`, which is good. That means you can substitute it for a mock in your test code and then perform verifications on it. Look into using [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: `wss = worker.Worker` should be `wss = worker.Worker(ws)`. And you can mock `ws`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.ws = ws

    def wssender(self, str):
        newstr = '<br>{0}'.format(str)
        self.ws.sendMessage(newstr.encode())

class WorkerTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_wssender(self):
        # Arrange
        ws = MagicMock()
        ws.sendMessage = MagicMock()
        worker = Worker(ws)

        # Act
        worker.wssender('test send message')

        # Assert
        ws.sendMessage.assert_called_once_with(b'<br>test send message')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output**

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: This works and it helps me better understand mocking so i can try it on other functions (much more complicated than this one).  I understand I should break up code to smaller functions and test those, but this is useful for code that I have already written.

Answer (score 1):

I assume "class Worker(self)" is a typo and that it's really "class Worker(object)" (or any other base class).

wrt/ the first issue, you forgot to instanciate `Worker` in your test - you want:

```
ws = WhateverWsIsSupposedToBe()
wss=worker.Worker(ws)
wss.wssender(msg)
```

Totally unrelated but `wssender()` is not a good name for a method - `sender` is a noon, methods are actions and should use verbs, so `wssend()` (or just `send()` FWIW) would be better.

Now with the second issue, you have a couple options. If what you want to test is the message formatting, just split it in another method:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, ws)
        self.ws = ws

    def prepare(self, msg):
        return '<br>{0}'.format(msg).encode(...)

    def send(self, msg):
        self.ws.sendMessage(self.prepare(msg))
```

so now you can test `Worker.prepare(msg)` in isolation.

If you want to test that `Worker.send(msg)` calls `self.ws.sendMessage(...)` (and calls it with the expected argument), you will have to mock `ws`. You can do this manually:

```
 class MockWs(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.msg = None
     def sendMessage(self, msg):
         self.msg = msg

 class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_send(self):
        ws = MockWs()
        msg = 'test send message'
        wss=worker.Worker(ws)
        wss.send(msg)
        expected = "<br>test send message"
        self.assertEqual(ws.msg, expected)
```

Or you can use the `mock` library, cf Tacg's answer.

Comment: This helps, got it working, in this case don't want to modify old code, but going forward will attempt to break down code to smaller chunks.